# Python: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Tags: python, csv, typeerror

I have done some research on here and can't quite find the exact answer I'm looking for. So I figured I would reach out for some support. I have been working on a python script that will search a CSV and check if the last column is 'TRUE', if it is then it retrieves the id and hostname. Below I have posted the code and the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm sure it's a simple issue...

Probably should not my goal. I am trying to get this portion to list out each hostname with this "command". Is there even a way to do this or no?

```py
COMMANDS = ("get 'C:\\" + HOSTNAME_HOST + ".zip'")
```

Here is the CSV:

```
hostname,id,enabled
WIN10_PC,asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf,TRUE
WIN_Server,asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf,TRUE
```

Here is a sample of the script:

```py
import csv

AIDS_TO_EXECUTE = []
HOSTNAME_HOST = []
with open('hosts_to_execute.csv', 'rt') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for hostname, aid, enabled in data:
        if enabled == 'TRUE':
            AIDS_TO_EXECUTE.append(aid)
            HOSTNAME = (hostname)
            HOSTNAME_HOST.append(HOSTNAME)
            
COMMANDS = ("get 'C:\\" + HOSTNAME_HOST + ".zip'")

#print(COMMANDS)

print(HOSTNAME_HOST)
```

Error I am recieving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    COMMANDS = ("get 'C:\\" + HOSTNAME_HOST + ".zip'")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
```

Comment: The error is clear: `HOSTNAME_HOST` is not a string but a `list`. And we can't concatenate a list to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to get this portion to list out each hostname with this "command". Is there even a way to do this or no?

The simplest way is to put `COMMANDS = []` before the `for` loop and within the `if` block do

```
            COMMANDS.append("get 'C:\\" + HOSTNAME + ".zip'")
```

just like you did with `HOSTNAME_HOST`.

Alternatively, you could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
COMMANDS = ["get 'C:\\" + h + ".zip'" for h in HOSTNAME_HOST]
```

You could even replace the whole `for` loop with:

```
    AIDS_TO_EXECUTE, HOSTNAME_HOST, COMMANDS = \
        zip(*[(a, h, "get 'C:\\" + h + ".zip'") for h, a, e in data if e == 'TRUE'])
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you for your help! Such a simple fix... thank you for the different methods and explanation!